# SES not sending attachment but text is being received

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sendmail, amazon-ses

I'm using `SesClient's sendRawEmail()` and here's my Raw Email. I'm able to receive HTML message but not attachment there.

**Raw Message:**

```
Subject: Weekly Analytics Report - BleuPage Ultimate MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-type: multipart/alternative; 
boundary="d410de6c937c9bc6e2d50cfc1a6f116b860c558d" To: sohail@averox.com         
From: no-reply@bleupage.com --d410de6c937c9bc6e2d50cfc1a6f116b860c558d 
Content-Type: text/plain; Hi here's your weekly analytics report, PFA. 
--d410de6c937c9bc6e2d50cfc1a6f116b860c558d Content-Type: text/html; 
charset=iso-8859-1
Hi here's your weekly analytics report, PFA.

--d410de6c937c9bc6e2d50cfc1a6f116b860c558d Content-Type: application/pdf; 
name="weekly-595.pdf" Content-Description: "weekly-595.pdf" Content-
Disposition: attachment; filename="weekly-595.pdf"; size=45876; Content-
Transfer-Encoding: base64 
   //base_64_encoded_fileContents()
--d410de6c937c9bc6e2d50cfc1a6f116b860c558d Content-Type: application/pdf; 
name="weekly-596.pdf" Content-Description: "weekly-596.pdf" Content-
Disposition: attachment; filename="weekly-596.pdf"; size=49094; Content-
Transfer-Encoding: base64 
   //base_64_encoded_fileContents()
--d410de6c937c9bc6e2d50cfc1a6f116b860c558d--
```

I'm able to receive the text part but not attachments available.

Comment: The total size of the message, including attachments, must be smaller than 10 MB.

Comment: size is already less than 10MB, files are 45KB and 48KB.

Comment: solved using [Mail_mime](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.php)